# put mysql data to a java tablemodel

Tags: java, mysql

Starting point: a mysql DB with 3 columns labeled "year", "month", "name" then 31 colums representing the days in the month (d1...d31)

I have two pieces of code but can't find how to insert the second piece correctly into the first one.  Following is the first one and, correctly, shows headings and what is in `private Object[][] data = new Object[][] {}`

```
public class PonyTable {

      public static class ShipTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        
        private String[] headings = new String[] {
          "Year", "Month", "Name", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
          "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"  
        };
      
        int i=0,j=0;
        private Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
          { "2020", "6", "ALESSANDRIN",
             "M", "P", "M", "P",  "M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P",
             "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", 
             "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M", "P","M", "P", "M"
            }};
         
        public int getRowCount() { return data.length; }
        //public int getColumnCount() { return data[0].length; }
        public int getColumnCount() { return 34; }
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
          return data[row][column];
        }

        public String getColumnName(int column) {
          return headings[column];
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
          return data[0][column].getClass();
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        TableModel model = new ShipTableModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
        renderer.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.CENTER );
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(45);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(125);
        for (int i = 3; i < 34; i++) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(25);
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShipTable v1.0");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(1000, 200);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }    
}
```

Second piece of code reads from DB but writes the result in the console.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    String nome = rs.getString("nome");
    int anno = rs.getInt("anno");
    int mese = rs.getInt("mese");
    System.out.print( anno + " " + mese + " " + nome + " ");
    for (i = 1; i <= daysinmonth; i++) { 
        String day = "d" + i;
        String giorno = rs.getString(day);
        System.out.print( giorno + " " );
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I read many and many examples but can't find a solution. I know I have to insert read data into `private Object[][] data = new Object[][] {}` but... how to do it?

Comment: 1) there is no need to create custom TableModel. You can use the DefaultTableModel. Then if you want to add new data to the model you use the `addRow(...)` method. If you want to change existing data in the model you use the `setValueAt(...)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified tableModel, made some arrangements and now in **whatArray** there is the content of the table

My problem now is that I am not able link **String[] data** **whatArray** so to obtain a single string to visualize.
I would like to see in the table:

> anno mese nome d1....d31

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            int i = 0;
            ArrayList<String> what = new ArrayList<String>();

            String[] whatArr = new String[what.size()];
            while (rs.next()) {
                String anno = rs.getString("anno");
                String mese = rs.getString("mese");
                String nome = rs.getString("nome");
            
                for (i = 1; i <= daysinmonth; i++)
                {
                    String day = "d"+i; 
                    what.add(rs.getString(day));
                }    
                whatArr = what.toArray(whatArr);
                // create a single array of one row's worth of data
                String[] data = { anno, mese, nome} ;
                // and add this row of data into the table model
                tableModel.addRow(data);
                
                tableModel.addRow(whatArr);
            }
```